# Twitter api not authorized

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have the basic access level on twitter api ,

Heres my code ,

```
query = 'QUERY'
tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query="test", max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abpFK.png) 
does this error happen to anyone ? need help with this
i tried changing to new api key and access token , still not authorized

Comment: Can you show us how you authenticate ?

Comment: @RayaneStaszewski client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key='',
    consumer_secret='',
    access_token='',
    access_token_secret=''
) that's my auth code